# Java Best way to compare strings from 2 lists

Tags: java, list

I have 2 lists of objects and in each object is a string I need to compare to another list.

And update getters in the first object with values from the second object when there is a match.

Is this the best approach?  Or is there a way to do a lookup between both sets maybe some guava utility??

```
for(firstObject fo : list1)
{
    for (secondObject so : list2)
    {
        if (fo.getUserId().equals(so.getUserId()) )
        {
            fo.setName(so.getName());
            fo.setEmail(so.getEmail());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd consider making "equals" compare user IDs, and having a method to initialize from another instance. The first depends on your actual business logic.

Comment: After the change proposed by Dave, instead of nested loop (complexity O(n**2)) convert one list into a HashMap for fast lookup (complexity O(n)).

Comment: @maaartinus it's O(n*m)

Comment: @nachokk that distinction only matters if `m << n` which wasn't specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `list2` can be instead of `Map`

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
for(secondObject so : list2)
{  
  map.put(so.getUserId(),so);  
}
```

then it look like this:

```
 for(firstObject fo : list1)
  {  
     Object so = map.get(fo.getUserId());  
     if(null!=so)
       {  
         fo.setName(so.getName());  
         fo.setEmail(so.getEmail());  
       }  
  }
```

Comment: This looks like it makes sense

Comment: @DocHoliday This solution also has the advantage of being `O(n)` time complexity.